# how to convert a list of strings into a list of integers in python

Tags: python, list

if my list is

```
B = ['1,222,000', '234,444', '12,000,000']
```

how do I convert that to

[1222000, 234444, 12000000]

I tried

```
B = list(map(int, B)
```

but it gives the error,

invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,375,178'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use regular expressions and `map`:

```
import re
B = ['1,222,000', '234,444', '12,000,000']
new_b = list(map(lambda x:int(re.sub('\W+', '', x)), B))
```

Output:

```
[1222000, 234444, 12000000]
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the commas first like this:

```
B = [int(i.replace(',', '')) for i in B]
```